# sql server express 2008 r2 and VS2012, untrusted domain

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

I have a windows XP Pro in a vritual machine with SQL Server 2008 R2 and other computer in the same LAN and same workgroup with VS2012.

When I try to create a new connection in VS2012, I can see the server name, but when I trey to see the databases, I get an error that I am trying to connect from an untrusted domain.

I would like to know if it is possible to create a domain in windows XP Pro and add my two computers to the same domain.

By the moment, SQL Server are cofingurated only to use windows authentication, but no SQL Server authentication, because I would like to avoid to put user and password in my connection string of my app config file.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a domain controller to make a domain, so just having XP Pro won't do it I'm afraid.

However, if you have a Windows account with identical usernames & passwords on both machines then it should still "just work".  You can't put a Windows username/password in a SQL connection string - you'll need to run your code as that user.  That can be done by starting your application using RunAs (shift+right-click on shortcut and choose "Run as...", or use RunAs at the command prompt).

This is pretty brittle but so long as you make sure the passwords are kept in sync then you should be ok.